# Image scale and rotate javascript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I'm trying to rotate my image and after scale it. Actual size of image - 300x434 convert to 8x8.

```
    var c = dc.create('canvas', {
        id:'canvas_'+_id, 
        width:8, // HERE!!! 8x8
        height:8, // HERE!!! 8x8
    }, dom.byId('canses'));

    var ctx = dom.byId('canvas_'+_id).getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = res;

    ctx.translate(img.width/2, img.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(rot*(Math.PI/180));
    ctx.translate(-img.width/2, -img.height/2);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 8, 8); // HERE!!! 8x8
```

But canvas is empty ;(. If use an initial size all works fine.

```
    var c = dc.create('canvas', {
        id:'canvas_'+_id, 
        width:300,
        height:434,
    }, dom.byId('canses'));

    var ctx = dom.byId('canvas_'+_id).getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = res;

    ctx.translate(img.width/2, img.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(rot*(Math.PI/180));
    ctx.translate(-img.width/2, -img.height/2);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

Can u help me? Thanks! (Sorry for my english)

Comment: You have to wait for the image to load. Use `image.onload = function(){ blah blah... drawImage(....`

Comment: Image misses the visible part 8x8, mb need to adjust a little bit via translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render an image at a fixed size rotated about its center

```
// image is the image
// ctx is the context
var x = 100;  // where the center of the image will be
var y = 100;
var width = 8; // size to draw
var height = 8;
// scale and translate
ctx.setTransform(width / image.width, 0, 0, height / image.height, x, y);
// rotate image
ctx.rotate(rot);
// draw image
ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2,-image.height / 2);

// resets the default transform;
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)
```

Comment: and can somehow enhance the quality? I use this method for comparing images and quality of rotated images loses.

Comment: @o_flyer scaling from 434 to 8 pixels will be very poor quality. You can get a slight improvement by scaling down in steps. Half the scale, render the image, then scale the rendered image by half again, till you get to the size you want. But that will still be very poor. You should do the scaling to the source image via photoshop of some high quality image editor.